# What is the value of ConfigurationPropertyAttribute.DefaultValue when a default value has not been specified?

Tags: c#, configuration

The default value of the following configuration property is obvious. It is "Arial":

```
  [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "Arial", IsRequired = true)]
  public string Name
  {
     get { return (string)this["name"]; }
     set { this["name"] = value; }
  }
```

But, what if I remove the "DefaultValue" part, as follows?

```
  [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
  public string Name
  {
     get { return (string)this["name"]; }
     set { this["name"] = value; }
  }
```

In Visual Studio, the value of the DefaultValue property on the attribute is listed as {object}, and if I call .ToString() on it, I get "System.Object".

How do I check whether or not a default value has actually been specified on the attribute?

Comment: Can you show how you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the reference source, it looks like an object is created privately, meaning it cannot be accessed:

```
private object _DefaultValue = ConfigurationElement.s_nullPropertyValue;
```

(source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/ConfigurationPropertyAttribute.cs,31)

However, I was able to fix the problem as follows:

```
var isDefaultSpecified = propertyAttribute.DefaultValue != null && propertyAttribute.DefaultValue.GetType() != typeof(object);
```